# $this->load->helper('language'); is not working

Tags: codeigniter, helper, hmvc

My app is ready on development server. Works as expected.

I'm using latest XAMPP / Codeigniter / HMVC

When uploaded to production server there are no errors thrown.
Login page simply shows without text

Login view

```
<a href="login/switchLanguage/italian">
      <i class="icon-font"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo lang('language'); ?>
</a>
```

When executed, this is the output:

```
    <a href="login/switchLanguage/italian"><i class="icon-font"></i>&nbsp;</a>
                                                                          ^
                                                                          |
                                                                  Here's supposed 
                                                                 to write "Italian"
```

Login controller

```
    class Login extends MX_Controller{

        function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper('language');
        }

        function index($msg = NULL){
            $data['msg'] = $msg;
            $this->load->view('login', $data);
        }

        public function switchLanguage($language = "") {
                $language = ($language != "") ? $language : "english";
                $this->session->set_userdata('site_lang', $language);
                redirect(base_url());
        }
```

EDIT:

Application/config/hooks.php

```
    $hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
        'class' => 'LanguageLoader',
        'function' => 'initialize',
        'filename' => 'LanguageLoader.php',
        'filepath' => 'hooks'
    );
```

Application/hooks/Languageloader.php

```
    <?php 

    class LanguageLoader {
        function initialize() {
            $ci =& get_instance();
            $ci->load->helper('language');
            $site_lang = $ci->session->userdata('site_lang');
            if ($site_lang) {
                $ci->lang->load('login',$ci->session->userdata('site_lang'));
            } else {
                $ci->lang->load('login','english');
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

Example language file: application/language/italian/common_lang.php

```
    <?php
    //Application Global
    $lang["common_appName"] ="Customer App";
    $lang["common_search"] = "Cercare";
    $lang["common_search_go"] = "Andare";
    $lang["common_label_created_by"] = "Creato da";

    //Menus
    $lang["common_menu_home"] = "Home";
    $lang["common_menu_dashboard"] = "Cruscotto";
    $lang["common_menu_production"] = "Produzione";
    $lang["common_menu_inventory"] = "Inventario";
    $lang["common_menu_user_edit"] = "Modificare";
    $lang["common_menu_logout"] = "Il logout";
    $lang["common_menu_new_notifications"] = "Ci sono nuove notifiche";

    //Submenus
    $lang["common_submenu_dashboard"] = "Cruscotto";
    $lang["common_submenu_production"] = "Produzione";
    $lang["common_submenu_inventory"] = "Inventario";
    $lang["common_submenu_orderlist"] = "Lista ordini";
    $lang["common_submenu_calendar"] = "Calendario";
```

I've gone thru a lot of questions & answers unsuccessfully.

Any suggestions are very welcome ...

Thanks!

Comment: it reads the data from language files, I don't see you loading any language file in your controller

Comment: I´m using a hook in application/config/hooks.php

$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
    'class' => 'LanguageLoader',
    'function' => 'initialize',
    'filename' => 'LanguageLoader.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks'
);

Comment: Are you sure you have enabled the hooks option in the config file? application/config/config.php ?

Comment: Yes ahmad, on application/config/config.php hooks is:   $config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;

Comment: post example of the language file you loaded, you may change log_threshold to maximum level to debug this too, it will show you what's being loaded & what's not.

Comment: Thanks ahmad, I will try log_threshold ... As requested, posted language file example ...

Comment: The language loader loads files not directories, the example you posted shows that you expect it to load a directory which does not work.

Comment: @ahmad I´m loading files... which part do you believe i'm trying to load a directory? The example file is under application/language/italian directory and among other files this file is common_lang.php which i'm showing example content

Comment: Where did you load the common_lang? or where did you load the file that have the line 'language' in it? If you enabled logging the issue should be clear.

Comment: ahmad Thanks for your reply. I posted the file common_lang.php there are many other files (one per module) and login module have its own file called login_lang.php which includes the $lang["language"] = "italian"; line in it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont know whether you solved this issue or not. But i faced the same problem when i updated my project to main server.
The actual problem is with the file name.
In your hooks.php you mention filename as 'LanguageLoader.php' but i think you created a file Languageloader.php (Application/hooks/Languageloader.php). Please check this..